# Bison not creating y.tab.c file

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer, yacc

I am doing a project in which I have to identify asianation, arithmetic, logical and relational operators, my .l file has no problems as far as I know, but it is in my .y where I am having problems when trying to use YACC, it is not generating my y.tab.c file by using the command `bison -yd cy`

This is my .l file called p3.l

```
%option yylineno

%{
    #include "p3.tab.h"
    int nLinea = 1;
    int lineStart = 0;
    char buffer[1024] = "";
%}

%x STRING COMENTARIOML

DELIMITADORES "{"|"}"|"?"|":"|";"|","|"("|")"

OPERADORESBASICOS "+"|"-"|"*"|"/"|"%"|"."|"&"|"["|"]"|"~"|"|"|"^"|"<"|">"|"!"|"="|"#"|"%"

ENTERO  (0[xX][0-9A-Fa-f]+)|(0[0-7]+)|[0-9]+
REAL    ([0-9]\.?[0-9]+([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?)|(0[xX][0-9A-Fa-f]\.?[0-9A-Fa-f]+([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?)
CARACTER    (\'[^\n'\\]\')|(\'\\['"\?\\abfnrtv]\')|(\'\\[0-3]?[0-7]{1,2}\')|(\'\\x[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}\')

CIDENTIFICADOR [a-zA-Z\_]
IDENTIFICADOR [a-zA-Z\_0-9]
ESPACIOS (\n|\t|\ )

%%

"char"      { printf("(Lexer | Linea %d) Palabra reservada: %s\n", yylineno, yytext); return(CHAR); }
"double"    { printf("(Lexer | Linea %d) Palabra reservada: %s\n", yylineno, yytext); return(DOUBLE); }
"else"      { printf("(Lexer | Linea %d) Palabra reservada: %s\n", yylineno, yytext); return(ELSE); }
"float"     { printf("(Lexer | Linea %d) Palabra reservada: %s\n", yylineno, yytext); return(FLOAT); }
"for"       { printf("(Lexer | Linea %d) Palabra reservada: %s\n", yylineno, yytext); return(FOR); }
"if"        { printf("(Lexer | Linea %d) Palabra reservada: %s\n", yylineno, yytext); return(IF); } 
"int"       { printf("(Lexer | Linea %d) Palabra reservada: %s\n", yylineno, yytext); return(INT); }
"register"  { printf("(Lexer | Linea %d) Palabra reservada: %s\n", yylineno, yytext); return(REGISTER); }
"return"    { printf("(Lexer | Linea %d) Palabra reservada: %s\n", yylineno, yytext); return(RETURN); }
"struct"    { printf("(Lexer | Linea %d) Palabra reservada: %s\n", yylineno, yytext); return(STRUCT); }
"void"      { printf("(Lexer | Linea %d) Palabra reservada: %s\n", yylineno, yytext); return(VOID); }
"while"     { printf("(Lexer | Linea %d) Palabra reservada: %s\n", yylineno, yytext); return(WHILE); }

"--"    { printf("(Lexer | Linea %d) Operador: %s\n", yylineno, yytext); return(DMINUS); }
"++"    { printf("(Lexer | Linea %d) Operador: %s\n", yylineno, yytext); return(DPLUS); }

"=="    { printf("(Lexer | Linea %d) Operador: %s\n", yylineno, yytext); return(DEQUAL); }
"+="    { printf("(Lexer | Linea %d) Operador: %s\n", yylineno, yytext); return(PLUSEQUAL); }


{OPERADORESBASICOS} { printf("(Lexer | Linea %d) Operador: %s\n", yylineno, yytext); return(yytext[0]); }

{ENTERO}    { printf("(Lexer | Linea %d) Constante entera: %s\n", yylineno, yytext); return(INTEGER); }
{REAL}      { printf("(Lexer | Linea %d) Constante real: %s\n", yylineno, yytext); return(REAL); }
{CARACTER}  { printf("(Lexer | Linea %d) Carácter: %s\n", yylineno, yytext); return(CHARACTER); }

{ESPACIOS}                          { /* Se ignoran sin más */ }
{DELIMITADORES}                     { printf("(Lexer | Linea %d) Delimitador: %s\n", yylineno, yytext); return(yytext[0]); }
{CIDENTIFICADOR}?{IDENTIFICADOR}*   { printf("(Lexer | Linea %d) Identificador: %s\n", yylineno, yytext); return(IDENTIFIER); }


<COMENTARIOML>.
<COMENTARIOML>\n      { ++nLinea; }
<COMENTARIOML>"*/"    { printf("(Lexer | Linea %d) Comentario ignorado.\n", yylineno); BEGIN(INITIAL); }



\" {
    BEGIN(STRING);
    lineStart = yylineno;
    strncpy(buffer, "\"", 1024);
}

<STRING>[^\"\n"] {
    strcat(buffer, yytext);
}

<STRING>\n {
    ++nLinea;
    strcat(buffer, yytext);;
}

<STRING>\\\" {
    strcat(buffer, yytext);
}

<STRING>\" {
    strcat(buffer, yytext);
    BEGIN(INITIAL);
    printf("(Lexer | Linea %d) Cadena de caracteres: %s \n", lineStart, buffer);
    strncpy(buffer, "", 1024);
    return(CADENA);
}

.   {printf("(Lexer | Linea %d) ERROR: %s\n", yylineno, yytext);}

%%
```

This is my .y file called p3.y

```
%{ /* Codigo C */
    #include <stdio.h>
    
%}



/* Declaraciones de BISON */

%union {
    int valor_entero;
    double valor_real;
    char * texto;
}


/* Definición de los TOKENS */

%token <valor_real> REAL
%token <valor_entero> INTEGER
%token <texto> IDENTIFIER CHARACTER CADENA AUTO CHAR DOUBLE ELSE  EXTERN FLOAT FOR IF INT REGISTER RETURN STATIC STRUCT VOID WHILE

/* Definición de la ASOCIATIVIDAD y PRECEDENCIA de los operadores */

%right '=' PLUSEQUAL MINUSEQUAL
%left '<' '>'
%left '-' '+'
%right DMINUS DPLUS
%left ')'
%right '('

%expect 2

%%

/* Gramatica */

/********** BLOQUES ************/

programa : lista_bloques ;

lista_bloques: bloque
|  bloque  lista_bloques ;

bloque : definicion_funcion
| declaracion ;

definicion_funcion : IDENTIFIER bloque_instrucciones
| declaracion_tipo IDENTIFIER bloque_instrucciones ;

constante : INTEGER
| REAL
| CADENA
| CHARACTER ;

/********** DECLARACIONES ************/
declaracion : declaracion_tipo lista_nombres ';'
| declaracion_tipo ';' ;

identificador_list : IDENTIFIER
| IDENTIFIER identificador_list ;

declaracion_tipo: almacenamiento_list  tipo_basico_modificado
| tipo_basico_modificado ;

tipo_basico_modificado :  '[' IDENTIFIER ']'
| tipo_basico ;

almacenamiento : EXTERN
| STATIC
| AUTO
| REGISTER ;

almacenamiento_list : almacenamiento
| almacenamiento almacenamiento_list ;


tipo_basico : VOID
| CHAR
| INT
| FLOAT
| DOUBLE ;

struct_union : STRUCT ;


declaracion_struct_list : declaracion_struct
| declaracion_struct declaracion_struct_list;

declaracion_struct : tipo_basico_modificado lista_nombres ';' ;


lista_nombres : nombre
| nombre ',' lista_nombres ;

nombre : dato
| dato '=' elementos ;

dato : IDENTIFIER
| IDENTIFIER '['']'
| IDENTIFIER '[' expresion ']' ;

elementos : expresion
| '{' elementosLista '}' ;

elementosLista : elementos
| elementos ',' elementosLista ;



/********** EXPRESIONES ************/

expresion : expresion_logica
| expresion '-' expresion
| expresion '+' expresion ;

expresion_logica: expresion '<' expresion
| expresion '<''>' expresion ;


expresion_constante : INTEGER
| REAL
| CADENA
| CHARACTER
| '(' expresion ')' ;


expresion_funcional : IDENTIFIER '(' ')'
| IDENTIFIER '(' lista_expresiones ')' ;

lista_expresiones : expresion
| lista_expresiones ',' expresion ;


expresion_indexada : IDENTIFIER ;

expresion_postfija : expresion_constante
| expresion_funcional
| expresion_indexada
| expresion_postfija DPLUS
| expresion_postfija DMINUS ;

expresion_prefija : expresion_postfija
| DPLUS expresion_prefija
| DMINUS expresion_prefija
| operador_unario expresion_cast ;


operador_unario : '+'
| '-' ;

expresion_cast : expresion_prefija
| '(' nombre_tipo ')' expresion_cast ;

nombre_tipo : tipo_basico_modificado ;





/********** INSTRUCCIONES ************/

instruccion : bloque_instrucciones
| instruccion_expresion
| instruccion_bifurcacion
| instruccion_bucle
| instruccion_retorno ;

bloque_instrucciones : '{' '}'
| '{' declaracion_list '}'
| '{' instruccion_list '}'
| '{' declaracion_list instruccion_list '}' ;

declaracion_list : declaracion
| declaracion declaracion_list ;


instruccion_list : instruccion
| instruccion instruccion_list ;

instruccion_expresion : expresion ';'
| asignacion ';' ;



asignacion : expresion_indexada operador_asignacion expresion ;


operador_asignacion : '='
| PLUSEQUAL
| MINUSEQUAL ;

instruccion_bifurcacion : IF '(' expresion ')' instruccion
| IF '(' expresion ')' instruccion ELSE instruccion ;

instruccion_bucle : WHILE '(' expresion ')' instruccion
| FOR '(' ';' expresion ';' expresion ')' instruccion
| FOR '(' lista_asignaciones ';' expresion ';' expresion ')' instruccion ;

lista_asignaciones : asignacion
| asignacion ',' lista_asignaciones ;

instruccion_retorno : RETURN ';'
| RETURN expresion ';';



%%

int main (int argc, char * argv[ ])
{
    extern FILE * yyin;
    
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "USO: %s fichero\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }
    
    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!yyin) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fichero inexistente %s\n", argv[1]);
        return -1;
    }
    
    yyparse();
    fclose(yyin);
    
    
    return 1;
    
    
}

yyerror (char *s) { printf ("%s\n", s); }

int yywrap() { return 1; }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UAPz.png)

Comment: Don't put image, just copy paste the error message

Comment: In your question, you say that you're having problems with `bison`. But the linked image shows problems with `flex`. I downloaded your `.l` file and ran it with `flex` (no errors).

Comment: Your problem with your p3.l file is probably that it starts with a BOM. Why it starts with a BOM I don't know; it will have to do with the text editor you used. If you're not using a text editor, please find one and use it; it's not a good idea to write code with a word processor designed for formatted documents.

Answer (score 0):

> *it is not generating my y.tab.c file by using the command `bison -yd cy`*

Your file is called `p3.y`, but your `bison` command doesn't mention it; you're telling `bison` to process something called `cy`. (Does `cy` even exist and if so, does it contain valid definitions?)

Even if you correct that to `bison -yd p3.y`, Bison won't produce a `y.tab.c` if there are fatal errors in `p3.y`. You have to read the error messages and fix everything.